# Canon eos rebel t3i “error 70”

Tags: canon

I’m new to this but I’m having issues with my camera, a canon rebel eos t3i, sadly it got splashed by saltwater (not even fully submerged) but it wouldn’t turn on for a few days. I read that the chances of it working ever again were slim but today I put in a battery and it turned on and seemed fine until I went to take a picture. It says it is error 70, and that I should turn the camera off and on again and reinstall the battery but that didn’t work. Does anyone know if I would be better off shipping it in to get serviced or if it would be cheaper to just replace it. I heard that repairs an quickly add up and I wouldn’t want to do that if it’s gonna end up costing more than a replacement. Let me know if you have any suggestions, thanks!

Edit- I just found out that canon no longer offers service for this model camera so that narrows down my options

Comment: idk about Canon, but if it's been wet, Nikon won't touch them - & salt water is far worse than fresh. I'd think it's time for a new camera.

Comment: Also see https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/96993/57929

Comment: [This question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/96993/15871)  is about Nikon, but the answer is the same. Canon won't even attempt to repair a camera with internal salt water damage, because they would have to warranty the repair.

Comment: Ah shucks that stinks

Answer (score 0):

The corrosion water can cause is amazing. If anything ever gets wet, power down and remove the battery and drop into a container of rice.

Remove after a few days and test. If it works, great! If not, well, I found used t3i's going for $230-ish bucks. That most certainly means that you'd be better off just getting a new body over attempting to get a repair.