# What size lens do I need?

Tags: lens, sony

What size lens do I need? I am shooting video from a distance of about 10 to 11 feet away. I want to be able to go from a CU (top of head to mid-chest) to a full body shot (head to toe). I currently have a Sony NEX-5 with the standard lens the camera comes with. Advise on the type of lens to get?

Comment: Is "CU" close-up?

Comment: There are several questions about focal length to fill the frame.  For example this one.  http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15156/what-is-the-formula-for-percent-of-frame-filled-at-a-specific-distance-and-focal